# error with following iOS code, coldn't what's the exact error source

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have the following error when expand a UItableView section 
, basically, the section will add rows of cells to the current section and collapse the row of cells of the previously expaned section.

```
 [xtable beginUpdates];
[xtable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToInsert withRowAnimation:insertAnimation];


 [xtable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToDelete withRowAnimation:deleteAnimation];
[xtable  endUpdates];





  2012-06-29 00:47:11.953 [9869:207] *** Assertion failure in
  -[UIViewAnimation initWithView:indexPath:endRect:endAlpha:startFraction:endFraction:curve:
    animateFromCurrentPosition:shouldDeleteAfterAnimation:editing:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1912.3/UITableViewSupport.m:2522
```

looks like error is coming from the animation?

the animation part is just like this

```
UITableViewRowAnimation insertAnimation;
UITableViewRowAnimation deleteAnimation;
if (previousOpenSectionIndex == NSNotFound || sectionOpened < previousOpenSectionIndex) {
    insertAnimation =UITableViewRowAnimationTop;
    deleteAnimation =UITableViewRowAnimationBottom;
}
else {
    insertAnimation =UITableViewRowAnimationBottom;
    deleteAnimation =UITableViewRowAnimationTop;
}
```

I commented out the animation code, but it still does giving the same error related to animation.